# Is there any way that a React Component's position is set in its function (like by position's id)?

Tags: reactjs, json

I am trying to make a weekly schedule in React. There is this table with rows representing days and columns representing time periods.

```
<Row>   
    <Col lg="12" sm="10">
        <Card>
            <CardHeader className="text-right">
                <CardTitle tag="h4">Week</CardTitle>
            </CardHeader>
            <CardBody>
                <Table className="tablesorter" responsive>
                    <thead className="text-primary">
                        <tr>
                            <th className="text-center"></th>
                            <th className="text-center">9 to 10:30</th>
                            <th className="text-center">10:30 to 12</th>
                            <th className="text-center">12 to 13:30</th>
                            <th className="text-center">13:30 to 15</th>
                            <th className="text-center">15 to 16:30</th>
                            <th className="text-center">16:30 to 17</th>
                            <th className="text-center">17 to 18:30</th>
                            <th className="text-center">18:30 to 20</th>                      
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td className="CoursesPanel_first_column text-center">Monday</td>
                            <td>
                                <div id="01"></div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div id="02"></div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div id="03"></div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div id="04"></div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div id="05"></div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div id="06"></div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div id="07"></div>
                            </td>
                            <td className="text-center">
                                <div id="08"></div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td className="CoursesPanel_first_column text-center">Tuesday</td>
                            <td>
                                <div id="11"></div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div id="12"></div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div id="13"></div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div id="14"></div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div id="15"></div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div id="16"></div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div id="17"></div>
                            </td>
                            <td className="text-center">
                                <div id="18"></div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td className="CoursesPanel_first_column text-center">Wednesday</td>
                            <td>
                                <div id="21"></div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div id="22"></div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div id="23"></div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            <div id="24"></div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            <div id="25"></div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            <div id="26"></div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            <div id="27"></div>
                            </td>
                            <td className="text-center">
                            <div id="28"></div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td className="CoursesPanel_first_column text-center">Thursday</td>
                            <td>
                            <div id="31"></div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            <div id="32"></div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            <div id="33"></div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            <div id="34"></div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            <div id="35"></div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            <div id="36"></div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            <div id="37"></div>
                            </td>
                            <td className="text-center">
                            <div id="38"></div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td className="CoursesPanel_first_column text-center">Friday</td>
                            <td>
                            <div id="41"></div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            <div id="42"></div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            <div id="43"></div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            <div id="44"></div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            <div id="45"></div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            <div id="46"></div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            <div id="47"></div>
                            </td>
                            <td className="text-center">
                            <div id="48"></div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td className="CoursesPanel_first_column text-center">Saturday</td>
                            <td>
                            <div id="51"></div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            <div id="52"></div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            <div id="53"></div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            <div id="54"></div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            <div id="55"></div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            <div id="56"></div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            <div id="57"></div>
                            </td>
                            <td className="text-center">
                            <div id="58"></div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </Table>
            </CardBody>
        </Card>
    </Col>
</Row>
```

I have a json file input like this:

```
[
    {
        "id" : 1,
        "day" : "0",
        "time" : "1",
        "name" : "Math",
        "teacher" : "X",
        "room" : "A-1"
    },
    {
        "id" : 1,
        "day" : "0",
        "time" : "3",
        "name" : "Art",
        "teacher" : "Y",
        "room" : "B-3"
    }
]
```

I want to make a function which maps each class into its position in the week table.

For example the first class goes to the first day of the week (Monday in this table) and the first period (9 to 10:30).
Is there any way that I can specify the position in the function? For example, I have the div id of every table cell. I also add a div attribute to the json file like this:

```
[
    {
        "id" : 1,
        "day" : "0",
        "time" : "1",
        "name" : "Math",
        "teacher" : "X",
        "room" : "A-1",
        "div" : "01", //{day}{time}
    },
    {
        "id" : 1,
        "day" : "2",
        "time" : "3",
        "name" : "Art",
        "teacher" : "Y",
        "room" : "B-3"
        "div" : "23", //{day}{time}
    }
]
```

And the function finds its position in the table according to the "div".

Or any other way...
Thanks in advance!

Comment: @ruakh I mean something like "append" in function. The function gets the json file and maps it and returns a <div>. I also want it to set the position of the <div>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In React, you don't really deal with loose string references like `id`. You solve this problem by iterating the structure instead. This is a mind switch change -- you don't deal with imperative DOM modifications like "append". You write the JSX in a way that is declarative.

First, you can transform the structure programmatically to one which is keyed by the day, and then the period. This makes it easier to deal with later since it also includes "gaps" by using `null`. That makes it easier to loop over as to make empty cells correctly skipped over.

So for your second example, in my new code, `keyedTimetable` would come out looking like this:

[image]

```
import { useMemo } from 'react'

// ...

// Now inside your component

const timetable = [ // You did not show where you define this as you did not post your whole component, but you can leave it wherever it is currently.
    {
        "id" : 1,
        "day" : "0",
        "time" : "3",
        "name" : "Math",
        "teacher" : "X",
        "room" : "A-1",
    },
    {
        "id" : 1,
        "day" : "0",
        "time" : "1",
        "name" : "Art",
        "teacher" : "Y",
        "room" : "B-3"
    }
]

// Now transform the structure
const keyedTimetable = useMemo(() => {
  const emptyDay = () => ({ 0: null, 1: null, 2: null, 3: null, 4: null, 5: null, 6: null, 7: null })
  return timetable.reduce(
    (lessonsKeyedByDayAndPeriod, currentPeriod) => {
      lessonsKeyedByDayAndPeriod[currentPeriod.day][currentPeriod.time] = currentPeriod
      return lessonsKeyedByDayAndPeriod
    },
    {
      0: emptyDay(),
      1: emptyDay(),
      2: emptyDay(),
      3: emptyDay(),
      4: emptyDay(),
      5: emptyDay(),
    }
  )
}, [timetable])
```

So you can granularly access any given lesson now if you wanted by doing `keyedTimetable[<day>][<time>]`. For example, `keyedTimetable[2][3]` would give me the 4th period lesson on a Wednesday (remembering it starts at 0).

If you are wondering what `useMemo` is that's a built-in react hook. Here it ensures we don't do the transformation on every render (wasted CPU cycles). It will only recalculate when the base `timetables` structure changes.

Now we will also add a new component (you can put it in the same file) to stop ourselves from repeating code so much. This component will basically represent a single day in the table. It takes the new object for a single day in the `periods` prop, and loops over it, creating the lesson entries in the right cell. Additionally you can pass a `dayName` prop which is just the string for the day like "Monday" for example.

```
const DayRow = ({ periods, dayName }) => (
  <tr>
    <td className="CoursesPanel_first_column text-center ">{dayName}</td>
    {Object.entries(periods).map(([time, entry]) => {
      // I chose to display the name, teacher and room, but you can do whatever
      // The `&&` is a common react trick. It will only render the div if there is a lesson in this slot. It's the same as saying "if entry has something in it then render the following".
      return (
        <td key={time}>
          {entry !== null && (
            <div>
              {entry.name}
              <br />
              {entry.teacher}
              <br />
              {entry.room}
            </div>
          )}
        </td>
      )
    })}
  </tr>
)
```

Now in your render, you can add the new component for each day. Notice for the `periods` prop we are passing the relevant data from the new structure for the given day.

```
<Row>
  <Col lg="12" sm="10">
    <Card>
      <CardHeader className="text-right">
        <CardTitle tag="h4">Week</CardTitle>
      </CardHeader>
      <CardBody>
        <Table className="tablesorter" responsive>
          <thead className="text-primary">
            <tr>
              <th className="text-center "></th>
              <th className="text-center ">9 to 10:30</th>
              <th className="text-center ">10:30 to 12</th>
              <th className="text-center ">12 to 13:30</th>
              <th className="text-center ">13:30 to 15</th>
              <th className="text-center ">15 to 16:30</th>
              <th className="text-center ">16:30 to 17</th>
              <th className="text-center ">17 to 18:30</th>
              <th className="text-center ">18:30 to 20</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <DayRow dayName="Monday" periods={keyedTimetable[0]} />
            <DayRow dayName="Tuesday" periods={keyedTimetable[1]} />
            <DayRow dayName="Wednesday" periods={keyedTimetable[2]} />
            <DayRow dayName="Thursday" periods={keyedTimetable[3]} />
            <DayRow dayName="Friday" periods={keyedTimetable[4]} />
            <DayRow dayName="Saturday" periods={keyedTimetable[5]} />
          </tbody>
        </Table>
      </CardBody>
    </Card>
  </Col>
</Row>
```